# How do I use my own colors in android XML

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an XML file I created in the res/value folder and try to reference it by writing

`android:background="@colors/red"`

and it does not work.

I also tried placing this file in the `drawable` folder but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to `color` resources with `@color/name`, not `@colors/name`.

For example, in `res/values/whatever.xml`:

```
<color name="your_color_name">#12345678</color>
```

Then in a layout xml:

```
android:background="@color/your_color_name"
```

Comment: As always, I enjoy all the answers but I can only accept one. 

I chose this one because the others pointed out how to add colors, which I already knew.. my problem was that it just wouldn't work when I tried to reference them.

Removing the `s` from my filename "colors" when I was referencing it did the trick.

Why the hell do I have to not use the full name of my file?

Comment: @SpaceGhost The resource filename doesn't matter as long as it is in one of the `values` subfolders. What matters is that you're referring to a `color` resource defined in a `values` resource file.

Answer (score 2):

- Your color res file has to be under `res/values/` (You may add it to a qualifier res/values folder though)
- Add the color in this format:

  ```
  <resources>
      <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
  </resources>
  ```
- Refer to it using `@color/white`.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a color in your color.xml file like below,

```
<color name="aqua_blue">#6495ED</color>
```

And then use it below,

```
android:background="@color/aqua_blue"
```

Answer (score 1):

easy way

```
android:background="#8EE8B5"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
 <color name="fuchsia">#FF00FF</color>
 <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
 <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>
 <color name="gray">#808080</color>
 <color name="olive">#808000</color>
 <color name="purple">#800080</color>
 <color name="maroon">#800000</color>
 <color name="aqua">#00FFFF</color>
 <color name="lime">#00FF00</color>
 <color name="teal">#008080</color>
 <color name="green">#008000</color>
 <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
 <color name="navy">#000080</color>
 <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

make one xml named colors.xml in res and add color names and codes as you want custum